# Mongoose model custom event

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, event-handling, dom-events

I'm looking for the right way to attach events to my mongoose models/schema. My example model:

*currency.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var currencySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  }
});

var Currency = mongoose.model('Currency', currencySchema);
module.exports = Currency;
```

How to properly attach EventEmitter so I can emit event and catch it properly?

```
Currency.findOne({'name': name}, function (err, currency) {
    currency.emit("up","Event sent");
    callback(err, wallet);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`EventEmitter` needs to contains functions and another type of data than can't be stored in a MongoDB BSON. Allowed types are the following:

1. MinKey (internal type)
2. Null
3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles)
4. Symbol, String
5. Object
6. Array
7. BinData
8. ObjectID
9. Boolean
10. Date, Timestamp
11. Regular Expression
12. MaxKey (internal type)

More information in the MongoDB documents: [BSON types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/)

Comment: So should I wrap event mongoose model in other object and attach emmiter there?

Comment: He doesn't really want to store event handling logic in the database though.

Answer (score 0):

Would extending the Model work?

```
import events from 'node:events';

class CurrencyModel extends mongoose.Model {
  static emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

  static on(...args) {
    return this.emitter.on(...args);
  }

  static emit(...args) {
    return this.emitter.emit(...args);
  }
}

currencySchema.loadClass(CurrencyModel);
```

Then in your code you can call `Currency.emit('something')` and `Currency.on('something', callback)`.

You can also build in pre and post hooks like this:

```
currencySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.constructor.emit('save', this);

    next();
});
```

EDIT: if you want to use `currency.on` instead of the model "Currency.on" you can make on and emit instance methods, but I'd keep the emitter static - your memory usage would skyrocket.